# Query with several filter conditions in SQL

Tags: sql-server, join

I’ve following filter table which contains various filter conditions. And need to apply filter conditions based on certain rules.

```
Id  Condition   Parameter
1   Department  Sales
2   Division    International sales
3   Place       AMAR
4   Country     New York
```

Filter conditions should get apply on following sample records, it should return all the matching records, which matches above filter condition i.e. all records where Department is ‘Sales’ and Division is ‘International sales’ and Place is 'AMAR' and Country is 'USA'.

```
Id  Name    Place   Country     Department  Division            Sub-Division        Location
1   John    EMEA    UK         Sales        International Sales ---         London
2   Jim     AMAR    USA        Sales        International Sales ---         New York
3   Sally   AMAR    USA        Sales        International Sales ---         Chicago
4   Molly   AMAR    USA         Sales       International Sales ---         New York
5   Gorge   AMAR    USA         Sales       International Sales FR relations    New York
6   Kramer  APAC    Singapore   Sales       International Sales ---         Singapore
```

But following query doesn’t return expected output,

```
select *  from
Filter  T  
left outer join 
SampleData  T1 on (T.Parameter= 'Sales' AND T1.Department='Sales' ) 
AND (T.Parameter= 'International sales' AND T1.Division='International 
sales' 
)
AND (T.Parameter= 'New York' AND T1.Location='New York' ) 
AND (T.Parameter = 'AMAR' AND T1.Place='AMAR' )
```

Comment: please explain what you mean by "doesn't return expected output"? How so exactly?

Comment: ...firstly `T1` does not have a column called `Parameter` (if going by your supplied sample data). Thus this should not run as is

Comment: actually... it looks like you swapped your aliases around. `T` should be `T1` and vice versa

Comment: Your join is basically saying "the parameter from the filter table must be "Sales" and the parameter from the filter table must be "International Sales"... etc.  Those first two conditions on their own are impossible, as there's no single row in your filter table where the parameter matches both values at the same time.  In fact it's impossible for that condition to work.

Comment: Raised separate issue with additional details, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48321370/query-with-several-filter-conditions-on-column-in-sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is probably closer to what you need?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    sd.* 
FROM 
    SampleData sd
    INNER JOIN [Filter] f1 ON f1.Condition = 'Department' AND sd.Department = f1.Parameter
    INNER JOIN [Filter] f2 ON f2.Condition = 'Division' AND sd.Division = f2.Parameter
    INNER JOIN [Filter] f3 ON f3.Condition = 'Place' AND sd.Place = f3.Parameter
    INNER JOIN [Filter] f4 ON f4.Condition = 'Country' AND sd.Country = f4.Parameter;
```

I also fixed some problems with your data/ script, and came up with this working example:

```
CREATE TABLE #Filter (Id INT, Condition VARCHAR(50), Parameter VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO #Filter SELECT 1, 'Department', 'Sales';
INSERT INTO #Filter SELECT 2, 'Division', 'International Sales';
INSERT INTO #Filter SELECT 3, 'Place', 'AMAR';
INSERT INTO #Filter SELECT 4, 'Location', 'New York';
CREATE TABLE #SampleData (Id INT, Name VARCHAR(50), Place VARCHAR(50), Country VARCHAR(50), Department VARCHAR(50), Division VARCHAR(50), SubDivision VARCHAR(50), [Location] VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO #SampleData SELECT 1, 'John', 'EMEA', 'UK', 'Sales', 'International Sales', '---', 'London';
INSERT INTO #SampleData SELECT 2, 'Jim', 'AMAR', 'USA', 'Sales', 'International Sales', '---', 'New York';
INSERT INTO #SampleData SELECT 3, 'Sally', 'AMAR', 'USA', 'Sales', 'International Sales', '---', 'Chicago';
INSERT INTO #SampleData SELECT 4, 'Molly', 'AMAR', 'USA', 'Sales', 'International Sales', '---', 'New York';
INSERT INTO #SampleData SELECT 5, 'Gorge', 'AMAR', 'USA', 'Sales', 'International Sales', 'FR relations', 'New York';
INSERT INTO #SampleData SELECT 6, 'Kramer', 'APAC', 'Singapore', 'Sales', 'International Sales', '---', 'Singapore';
SELECT
    sd.* 
FROM 
    #SampleData sd
WHERE
    sd.Department = (SELECT Parameter FROM #Filter WHERE Condition = 'Department')
    AND sd.Division = (SELECT Parameter FROM #Filter WHERE Condition = 'Division')
    AND sd.Place = (SELECT Parameter FROM #Filter WHERE Condition = 'Place')
    AND sd.Location = (SELECT Parameter FROM #Filter WHERE Condition = 'Location');
```

Gives these results, i.e. the people who match the filter:

```
Id  Name    Place   Country Department  Division                SubDivision     Location
2   Jim     AMAR    USA     Sales       International Sales     ---             New York
4   Molly   AMAR    USA     Sales       International Sales     ---             New York
5   Gorge   AMAR    USA     Sales       International Sales     FR relations    New York
```

Comment: Thanks Richard Hansell for your reply, it resolved my problem, the query should dynamically check various conditions like ‘Department’ and ‘Country’ only. Could it be possible?

Comment: How would you control the dynamic filter, i.e. how would you control which conditions are to be included and which aren't?  One way you could do this would be to extend your [Filter] table to have a new column with a bit type called [active] or something like that.  Then you could update the [active] values in each row of the [Filter] table depending on what sort of match you wanted to perform?  Is this anything like what you are thinking of, or am I missing the point here?

Answer (score 0):

I think your 4th rule is Location and not Country, like

```
4   Location     New York
```

The following code will work dynamically, how much ever rules you add to the rules table :

```
DECLARE @tmp VARCHAR(250)
DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(max)
SET @tmp = ''
SELECT @tmp = @tmp + Condition +  ' = ''' + Parameter + ''' and ' from FilterTable

SELECT @tmp = SUBSTRING(@tmp,0,LEN(@tmp)-3)
SELECT @tmp
SELECT @Query = 'Select * from SampleData where '+ @tmp

EXEC (@Query)
```

Hope this helps, even though its a bit perfomance costly.

[image: Tested]

Comment: `UPDATE FilterTable SET Condition = ';DROP DATABASE;';`

Comment: DROP DATABASE? for what?

Comment: Can we dynamically check various conditions like ‘Department’ and ‘Country’ only?