# Query with several filter conditions on column in SQL

Tags: sql-server, join

I’ve following data which contain Training, Filter and User records. Following script will create desire tables, need to apply filter conditions based on certain rules.

```
CREATE TABLE #Training (Id INT, Topic VARCHAR(50), [Status] VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO #Training SELECT 1, 'International Sales Training', 'Active';
INSERT INTO #Training SELECT 2, 'AMAR Sales Training', 'Active';
INSERT INTO #Training SELECT 3, 'APAC Sales Training', 'Active';
INSERT INTO #Training SELECT 4, 'General Training', 'Active';
INSERT INTO #Training SELECT 5, 'Manager Training', 'Active';

 CREATE TABLE #Filter (Id INT, Condition VARCHAR(50), Parameter VARCHAR(50), TrainingId int);
 INSERT INTO #Filter SELECT 1, 'Department', 'Sales', 1;
 INSERT INTO #Filter SELECT 2, 'Division', 'International Sales', 2;
 INSERT INTO #Filter SELECT 3, 'Place', 'AMAR', 2;
 INSERT INTO #Filter SELECT 4, 'Designation', 'Manager', 1;
 INSERT INTO #Filter SELECT 5, 'Designation', 'Developer', 4;

 CREATE TABLE #User (Id INT, Name VARCHAR(50), Place VARCHAR(50), Country 
 VARCHAR(50), Department VARCHAR(50), Division VARCHAR(50), SubDivision 
 VARCHAR(50), [Location] VARCHAR(50), Designation VARCHAR(50));
 INSERT INTO #User SELECT 1, 'John', 'EMEA', 'UK', 'Sales', 'International 
 Sales', '---', 'London', 'Manager';
 INSERT INTO #User SELECT 2, 'Jim', 'AMAR', 'USA', 'Sales', 'International Sales', '---', 'New York', 'Manager';
 INSERT INTO #User SELECT 3, 'Sally', 'AMAR', 'USA', 'Sales', 'International Sales', '---', 'Chicago', 'Sr. Manager';
 INSERT INTO #User SELECT 4, 'Molly', 'AMAR', 'USA', 'Sales', 'International Sales', '---', 'New York', 'Manager';
 INSERT INTO #User SELECT 5, 'Gorge', 'AMAR', 'USA', 'Sales', 'International Sales', 'FR relations', 'New York', 'Developer';
 INSERT INTO #User SELECT 6, 'Kramer', 'APAC', 'Singapore', 'Sales', 'International Sales', '---', 'Singapore', 'Manager';
```

What I’m struggling to get filter training records for matching criteria, i.e. following example (for UserId 2) it should give Training details where it matches Department and Designation only .i.e. TrainingID 1. But I’m getting 3 record due to OR condition.

```
 Declare @Department VARCHAR(50),@Division VARCHAR(50), @Designation VARCHAR(50)

 SELECT @Department = Department, @Division = Division,@Designation=Designation from #User where id=2

 SELECT DISTINCT TR.ID
       FROM #Training TR
       LEFT OUTER JOIN #Filter F ON TR.ID = F.Id AND TR.Status = 'Active'
    WHERE 
    (
                (
                    (F.Condition='Department' and F.Parameter = @Department )                       
                )
                OR
                (
                     (F.Condition='Division' and F.Parameter = @Division)   
                )
                OR
                (
                     (F.Condition='Designation' and F.Parameter = @Designation) 
                )
    )
```

Comment: If you don't want three matches (which is what that logic is giving you) then can give us other logic for retaining only one of the matches?

Comment: the matches  can change based on filter criteria, i.e. Filter can be apply to Country and Place etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match all three, then use `group by` and `having`:

```
SELECT TR.ID
FROM #Training TR JOIN
     #Filter F
     ON TR.ID = F.Id AND TR.Status = 'Active'
WHERE (F.Condition = 'Department' and F.Parameter = @Department) OR 
      (F.Condition = 'Division' and F.Parameter = @Division) OR
      (F.Condition = 'Designation' and F.Parameter = @Designation) 
GROUP BY TR.ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT F.Condition) = 3;
```

You can change the `HAVING` clause if you don't want all three to match.

Comment: (0 row(s) affected)

Comment: @Satish . . . I realize that I don't understand the question.  Why would you want id where only two conditions match?  You can change the `HAVING` condition to `COUNT(DISTINCT f.Condition) >= 2`.

Comment: COUNT(DISTINCT f.Condition) >= 2 doesn't work, return 0 records, the match condition can change based on filter criteria, i.e. Filter can be apply to Country and Place etc so it would be difficult to hard-code count value.

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this solution with output..**

```
Declare @Department VARCHAR(50),@Division VARCHAR(50), @Designation VARCHAR(50)
SELECT @Department = Department, @Division = Division,@Designation=Designation from #User where id=2
SELECT *
       FROM #Training TR
       LEFT OUTER JOIN #Filter F ON TR.ID = F.Id AND TR.Status = 'Active'
    WHERE 

           F.Condition = 'Department' AND  F.Parameter = @Department
       OR F.Condition = 'Division' AND F.Parameter = @Division
       OR F.Condition = 'Designation' AND F.Parameter = @Designation
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Id          Topic                                              Status                                             Id          Condition                                          Parameter                                          TrainingId
----------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- ----------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -----------
1           International Sales Training                       Active                                             1           Department                                         Sales                                              1
2           AMAR Sales Training                                Active                                             2           Division                                           International Sales                                2
4           General Training                                   Active                                             4           Designation                                        Manager                                            1

(3 rows affected)
```

Comment: Getting 5 records back, instead of 1

Comment: can you please provide what rows you are getting and the output you need. Thanks.

Comment: Getting following result 
ID
1
2
3
4
5

Comment: and what should we need as output.

Comment: Only Topic " International Sales Training " should get fetch as it is matching Department and Designation condition.

Comment: No only the Department is matching for first row. Designation is not different for the first row.

Comment: In the Filter table, Training id 1 is mapped to Department 'Sales' and Designation "Manager'. hence I'm looking for a query which will return Training id 1, where the condition matches

Answer (score 0):

I think there is wrong column used for joining the table and need some fixes in your query as below

```
SELECT DISTINCT TR.ID
FROM #Training TR
LEFT OUTER JOIN #Filter F ON TR.ID = F.TrainingId AND
                             TR.Status = 'Active' AND
                            ((F.Condition='Department' and F.Parameter = @Department) OR 
                             (F.Condition='Division' and F.Parameter = @Division) OR
                             (F.Condition='Designation' and F.Parameter = @Designation) )
```

Comment: Getting following result ID 1 2 3 4 5